# Examples of comma rules

Tags: punctuation, commas

I am refreshing - or rather building up from scratch =) - my knowledge about the proper usage of commas in the English language. I would like if you could take a look at the subsequent examples and check if they are correct.

1. Due to/Since/Because ...., we can...

   > A comma because the first clause is an adverbial "clause of reason". If the dependent clause would stay behind the main clause, then there would be no need for a comma.
2. A converges to B, locally uniformly.

   > Here, I am not sure. It looks better with a comma for me, but I believe, there is no need for a comma since the second clause is essential ?
3. We saw the key which we will need later on the roof.

   > Here, I am not sure. Does the comma-usage here just depends on the essentiality of the clause introduced by which?
   >      The car which had the most people in it weights the most. -> essential clause
   >   The car, which looked very nice, weights 1200 Kg.-> non-essential clause
4. "Thus/Therefore/Hence" at the beginning of a sentence: Comma right after the word? I think, no.
5. It states that if ..., then ....

Comment: If you're going to do a paper on "proper usage .. in the english language," you should remember the it's always spelled capitalized: i.e., "English".

Comment: This looks like five questions to me.

Comment: This is a nice source for comma usage: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Correct. If the dependent clause concludes the sentence, no comma is necessary. Example: "We can drive to the island because the bridge is open."
2. Your example sentence is not clear enough for me to understand what you are asking, but I *think* you are giving an example in which a comma is preferred.
3. Yes. Whether the clause is essential or not determines the need for the comma. *Essential*, however, is not the usual grammatical term. *Restrictive* is the term you are looking for. If the clause is restrictive (essential), then you do not use commas.
4. This one is not hard and fast. A comma tends to be used, but not always.
5. This one is also somewhat a matter of preference.

Comma rules are complicated, numerous, and debatable, and sometimes come down to a matter of stylistic preference of the author. Most of us who want to learn about commas tend to refer to the work of a teacher named Larry Trask, who put a rather long work about commas online at this URL:

http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/

Go there, and be enlightened. :)

Comment: Much obligded, I will risk a look, or two.
The two comments to the original post are also very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Two rules for commas. Even three:

No comma if a conjunction is inside, not at the beginning:

- Call me [no comma] if you are free.
  but:
- If you are ill, you ought to see a doctor.

No comma before a clause which provides no extra information:

- This is the man [no comma] I saw yesterday.
  but:
- I went to the London Palladium, which a friend of mine recommended.

No comma after *please* at the beginning:

- Please come in.
  but:
- Come in, please.

Comma rules have many issues and I came across a large PDF to study. It's not that easy to answer.